# machine learning, calculating cost function error, get size 0 matrix as the result

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+np.asmatrix(np.exp(-x)))

def graD(X,y,alpha,s0,numda):
    m=np.size(X,0)
    n=np.size(X,1)
    X0=X[:,0]
    X1=X[:,1:]

    theta=np.asmatrix(np.zeros(np.size(X,1))).T
    s=100
    lit=0
    Jlist=[]

    while abs(s)>s0 and lit<=10000:
        theta0=theta[0]
        theta1=theta[1:]


        theta0-=(float(alpha)/m)*X0.T*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y)
        theta1-=float(alpha)*((1.0/m)*X1.T*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y)+float(numda)/m*theta1)
        theta=np.vstack((np.asmatrix(theta0),np.asmatrix(theta1)))

        Jlist.append( cost(X,y,theta,numda) )

        lit+=1
        s=sum((float(1.0)/m)*X.T*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y))/float(n)

    plot.scatter( range(0, len(Jlist)), Jlist )

    return theta


def cost(X,y,theta,numda):
    m=X.shape[0]

    J = (-1.0/m)*( (-y).T*np.log( sigmoid(X*theta) ) - (1-y).T*np.log(1- sigmoid(X*theta) )  ) + (numda/ (m*2)) * (theta[0,1:].T * theta[0,1:]  )
    return J
```

I have printed out the result of the function cost which calculates the cost function for logistic regression, but I found that it is a `[]` with a length 0

also, I tried it separately using:

```
c(X,y,theta,30)
Out[69]: matrix([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float64)
```

and the problem also exists, I am new to ml and python, and I really can not solve this problem

Comment: What are the inputs X, y and theta that you use?

Comment: @DavidMasip Thank you for your attention, but I have solved the problem just now, it is because I have to use      theta[ 1 :  ]    instead of   theta[ 0,1:  ] for the dimention of theta is n*1

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is:

```
def cost(X,y,theta,numda):
    m=X.shape[0]

    J = (-1.0/m)*(np.dot(-y.T, np.log(sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta)))) - np.dot(1-y.T, np.log(1-sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))))) + (numda/(m*2)) * (np.linalg.norm(theta[1:])**2)
    return J
```

In numpy, * is the element-wise product, while `np.dot()` is the matrix product. I think that was your main confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have solved this problem but it is due to the incorrect use of slicing in the " theta[ 0,1: ] " , I have to write like " theta[ 1: ] ". I made a mistake there

Comment: You are right, but still you have to use dot, right?

Comment: It is better to use dot symbol because it can avoid mistakes for it stands for both type 'matrix' and type 'ndarray', but there I have transferred the parameters inputted to matrix so I think there maybe no problem :)

Comment: But now I have found that the correct rate of the predictions down by this regression is quite low, so I think there may be some mistakes with the algorithm    :-(